# EntityFramework Automatic Migrations with Azure Git Deployment

Tags: entity-framework

I have a setup whereby when running locally in Debug my Web.Config configures EntityFramework to use my custom `DbInitializer` (inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`). However, I have a Release transform that switches out this dev `DbInitializer` for a `MigrateToLatestVersion` initializer.

The plan is that when I do a Git deploy I want it to run all my migrations.
However, this isn't currently happening. I have to do a Git deploy and then manually change the Web.Config connection string to point to the live database and in the Package Manager Console perform a `update-database`.

Does anybody know how I can get Azure to do this step automatically? I assumed that was what `EnableAutomaticMigrations` was for in the `Configuration` class, but no joy.

Cheers

Comment: Tom, did you manage to resolve this?