# CodeFirst DB Migrations with Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I've so far been unsuccessful at getting automatic migrations to work from a Visual Studio Online Code Repo that's configured to automatically deploy to Azure.

There's a Similar Question here that's unanswered:
[EntityFramework Automatic Migrations with Azure Git Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469139/entityframework-automatic-migrations-with-azure-git-deployment)

My issue right now, is that the databases get out of Sync between the local working copy and the Azure DB, so when the code deploys successfully, the application no longer functions, since the database is not updated to match the new classes.

I've tried Several approaches:

1. Webapi.config updated to include a Migrator.

   ```
   var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
   migrator.Update();
   ```
2. Web.Config Updated to Include Migrate To Latest Version

   ```
   <add key="MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion" value="true"/>
   ```
3. Migrations Configuration Updated to Enable Automatic

   ```
   AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
   ```
4. Publishing Directly from Visual Studio Via the Publish Manager - This still doesn't execute the DB Updates on the Azure site. (Including Checking the Option Box to Execute Migrations)

Anyone been able to get this to work?

Edit: I've also tried this, unsuccessfully, as a post deploy work-around, but no luck either.
http://robertgreiner.com/2012/05/using-entity-framework-database-migrations-to-update-a-remote-database/

Comment: Perhaps Important to Mention, I changed the name of one of my classes, so it's possible this is caused by a data loss prevention issue, but I've added AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; to the Configuration.cs File in the Migrations Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've Discovered what I believe to be the root cause (Code Wise, Actual Root Cause is I'm an idiot). I have configured in the web.config the LocalDB Client, to  the migrations were all happening against that DB. Commenting out that DB and allowing the Update-Database Command in the package manager to run against the AzureDB updated the database on Azure correctly.

I'm still not totally sure why the migrations aren't working, but I'm suspecting it's due to the Web.Config File I'm deploying with the default DB set to something Azure doesn't know about (LocalDB).

So this is a work-around at least, while I fix my Web.Config Settings to deploy with the correct DB to Azure.